# posting multiple parameters in jsonobjectrequest volley

Tags: android, opentok, jsonobjectrequest

I need to post multiple parameters in postbody in Jsonobject postbody here.I searched all over stack but cudnt find out.please help me

```
public void startArchive(String sessionId) {
    JSONObject postBody = null;
    try {
        postBody = new JSONObject("{\"sessionId\": \"" + sessionId + "\"}");
    } catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Parsing json body failed");
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    this.reqQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, OpenTokConfig.ARCHIVE_START_ENDPOINT,
            postBody,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "archive started");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            delegate.onWebServiceCoordinatorError(error);
        }
    }));
}
```

my parameters

```
{
"sessionId" : "session_id",
"hasAudio" : true,
"hasVideo" : true,
"name" : "archive_name"
"outputMode" : "composed",
```

}

I need to include this as well

```
  Content-Type:application/json
```

postman gives this response[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can send `JsonObject` Request with using `Volley library`. See below code , Hope this will help you .

```
     try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{" +
                        "\"sessionId\":\"" + sessionId + "\"," +
                        "\"hasAudio\":\"" + hasAudio + "\"," +
                        "\"hasVideo\":\"" + hasVideo + "\"," +
                        "\"outputMode\":\"" + outputMode + "\"}");

                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(YOUR_URL , jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Utils.hideProgressDialog();
                        try{
                            if(response!=null){
                                // do something with the response 
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ops, Something wrong. Try again later. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      // Handle Error . 
                    }
                }) 
                @Override 
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();                
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return params; 
                } ;


                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, "json_object");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ops, Something wrong. Try again later. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**Add The AppController Class As Below :**

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

    }
    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }



}
```

**Add `AppContoller` in your `Manifest.xml` file in `<application>` tag .**

```
 <application
        android:name=".AppController">  ...... </application>
```

Comment: please send me AppController class as well as I am not using that in my code

Comment: Edited My Answer. Let me know if it's works  or you are facing any problem .

Comment: Can you give a snapshot of your request using Postman or ARC.  And also debug the object values you are sending .

Comment: i need to include this in my code 'Content-Type:application/json'.maybe thats why i am getting that error.can u help me?

Comment: postman  gives this response {
    "code": -1,
    "message": "No suitable authentication found"
}

Comment: give me a screenshot how you sending the request . Do you able to check the api for success case using postman.  Give me a sucess request snapshot .

Comment: i have edited my question with the postman screenshot.pls chk

Comment: Your request should on Body > raw > Json(application/json) and the value should be on 
{
 "sessionId":"45990752",
 "hasAudio":"true", 
 "hasVideo":"false",
 "name":"able",
 "outputMode":"composed"
}


Also there is athentication problem . You need to talk with the server side developer if he used any authentication with the request  or not . If not tell him to give you snapshot of success request using postman .

Comment: atleast postman gives response.But my android code is not even getting that response

Comment: You get the response code unexpected 403 that the equivalent of postman response code . You can see the response too, try to debug the respone object .

Comment: I am not getting any log in OnResponse.But as u have clarified about the authentication I think I need to contact the server side developers now,Thank u so much

Comment: For getting  log  you have to Log.d("respone", respone) ;  in onResponse() .  Let me know how you solve it in future . I think my codes will works fine , if you can confirm from server side .

Comment: sure i will let u know

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this thing.!
You can send  `JSON Object` Request try below `method` .

```
HashMap<String, String> parrams = new HashMap<String, String>();
parrams.put("sessionId", "session_id");
parrams.put("hasAudio", "true");
parrams.put("hasVideo", "true");
parrams.put("name", "archive_name");
parrams.put("outputMode", "composed");

JsonObjectRequest requestCall = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, OpenTokConfig.ARCHIVE_START_ENDPOINT,
       new JSONObject(parrams) ,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "archive started");
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        delegate.onWebServiceCoordinatorError(error);
    }
}));


Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(requestCall);
```

Comment: where to add requestCall?

Comment: Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(requestCall);

Comment: Kindly post Your whole Code.?

Comment: I have found out it is due to autentication problem of the server.JWT token is required.anyways thanks